# How to import and using package npm as classnames with file.jsx in project ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

I have project ASP.NET CORE MVC using Reactjs and I want to use npm package classnames in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).
I have a file .jsx and I want to import classNames to this file use.
In React, I can import and use it follow: 
*import classNames from 'classnames*
but In ASP.NET CORE MVC, I can't use that way to import it.

How do I can use it in this project ? Thanks you

[You can see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6EFg.png)

Comment: Hi,
ASP.NET is C# backend environment, React is a javascript front-end library, you can't mix them.
Did you mean "How to manage React project in visual studio?" ?

Comment: Anyway, the .NET WebApi project template is more suitable for integrate React.